# Generate a Date series between transaction dates

Tags: postgresql

I have a table which contains transaction dates and the balances of those transactions. Example Below:

```
select id, transaction_bal1, transaction_bal2, transaction_date
from transactions
```

Which results in

```
ID | transaction_bal1 | transaction_bal2 | transaction_date
1  | -10000           | 1000             | 2017.01.02
2  | 4000             | 1000             | 2017.02.02
3  | 4000             | 1000             | 2017.03.02
etc...
```

What I want to do is to generate a series with '1 day'::interval so that I select all days between the transaciton dates and that the rows in the above table falls under the right day. Something like this:

```
Gen_series | ID | transaction 1 | transaction 2 | transaction_date
2017.01.01 |null| 0             | 0             | null
2017.01.02 |1   | -10000        | 1000          | 2017.01.02
2017.01.03 |null| 0             | 0             | null
...
2017.02.01 |null| 0             | 0             | null
2017.02.02 |1   | 4000          | 1000          | 2017.01.02
2017.02.03 |null| 0             | 0             | null
etc...
```

I use Postgresql(dont know which version) but I use PgAdmin 4 3.2 (if that is of any help)

Feel free to ask any questions if I need to flesh out anything.

Comment: The IDs should be the same as this is a query for a specific contract (1)

Comment: Are you sure you want  transaction_date 2017.01.02 in the same row with Gen_series 2017.02.02 ?

Comment: That seems easy. Join with the result of the `generate_series` table function.